# How to send D3D Device by giving reference ( DirectX/C++ Prgoramming )

Tags: c++, pointers, directx, directx-9

H1.
I'm trying to depart my codes into different **.cpp** and **.h** files to make them find, see and understand easier. Here is what I'm trying to do now: I got a **Meshes.cpp** wich is my main **.cpp** source file. In the **Render** function ( **Render()** ) I have to call a function that named **SetupMatrices**:

This is my "**d3dGeneral.cpp**" file:

```
// Begining of the "d3dGeneral.cpp"
    #include "DXUT.h"

    VOID SetupMatrices( LPDIRECT3DDEVICE9 *PDev )
    {
        D3DXMATRIXA16 matProj;
        D3DXMatrixPerspectiveFovLH( &matProj,
                                    D3DX_PI / 4,
                                    1.777777777777778f,
                                    1.0f,
                                    1000.0f );    
        PDev->SetTransform( D3DTS_PROJECTION, &matProj ); // The problem is here......
    }
//Enging of the "d3dGeneral.cpp"
```

And this is my "**Meshes.cpp**" file: (Which is main cpp file)

```
// Begining of the "Meshes.cpp" file.
#include "DXUT.h"
#include "XMesh.h"
#include "Camera.h"
#include "d3dGeneral.cpp"

...
...
//Usualy SetupMatrices is found here.
...
...

VOID Render()
{
    SetupMatrices( &g_pd3dDevice );
    ...
    ...
    ...
}
INT WINAPI wWinMain( HINSTANCE hInst, HINSTANCE, LPWSTR, int nCmdShow)
{
    ...
    ...
    ...
    Render();
    ...
    ...
    ...
}
// End of the "Meshes.cpp" file
```

The header file named **DXUT.h** contains other general includes.
So, when I do this I get an error:

**Error 2   error C2227: left of '->SetTransform' must point to class/struct/union/generic type c:\users\catt\desktop\deneme\d3dgeneral.cpp 74  MeshClass**

I know what that means, but I can't findout how to avoid from it. Looks like I have a problem with pointers. Also I tryed to use PDev like this:

```
*PDev->SetTransform( D3DTS_PROJECTION, &matProj );  // ???
```

I know I don't have to use d3dDevice with reference in that function, but I also have a function **Cleanup**. I think I need to give refrence for it, because it have to clean the real Device itself not the copy of it 8).  I hope I explained myself correctly. If you can help me that will be awsome. Thank you for giving your time...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried this:

```
(*PDev)->SetTransform( D3DTS_PROJECTION, &matProj );
```

Answer (score 2):

`LPDIRECT3D9DEVICE` is *already* a pointer. You don't need a pointer to it. Just take `LPDIRECT3D9DEVICE` by value.

Of course, I personally prefer to take an `IDirect3D9Device*`, as it's clearer, and in addition, I like to store the original pointer in a smart pointer.

Comment: Thank you for response. I tryed to use it without pointer: Than it says there is conversation error... Probly I did something work... The one Cem Kalyoncu said is worked for me.